# How to add a button/default UICollectionViewCell at IndexPath 0 without getting "Fatal error: Index out of range"

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to add a default cell to use as a "Add New" button in my cellForItemAt method whilst still returning the correct number of items in my collection view, however, the methods I have tried either return an incorrect number of items or cause a crash **Index out of range**

I'm trying to achieve this.

[image]

This is my numberOfItemsInSection method.

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if collectionView == newsCollectionView {
        if newsArticles.count > 0 {
            return newsArticles.count + 1
        } else if newsArticles.count == 0 {
            return 1
        }
    }

    return 0
}
```

This is my cellForItemAt method

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if collectionView == newsCollectionView {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "newsDefaultCell", for: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell

            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "newsArticleCell", for: indexPath) as! newsArticleCell

            cell.news = newsArticles[indexPath.row + 1]

            return cell
        }
    }

    return UICollectionViewCell()
}
```

I know that this line is causing the crash

```
return newsArticles.count + 1
```

I'm just looking for an alternative way of doing it without returning 1 less item than I should, any help is hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding when you should subtract.

Replace this line:

```
cell.news = newsArticles[indexPath.row + 1]
```

with:

```
cell.news = newsArticles[indexPath.row - 1]
```

Because when the `indexPath.row` is `1`, you want the first item from your array (ie. the item at index `0`).

---

Also, you can simply your `numberOfItemsInSection` by observing that if `newsArticles.count` is `0`, then `newsArticles.count + 1` will be `1`, so there's no reason to special case it.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if collectionView === newsCollectionView {
        return newsArticles.count + 1
    }

    return 0
}
```

*Note*:  Use `===` instead of `==` to check that the two items are references to the same object.